# Hacer que el metodo disminuya los objetos usando iterador

Tags: java, iteradores

```
public Automotor disminuirEjemplares(int ejemplar, String modelo){
    Automotor modeloEncontrado = null;
  Iterator<Automotor> it = this.listaDeAutomotores.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext() && modeloEncontrado == null){
       Automotor a = it.next();
            modeloEncontrado = a;
            modeloEncontrado.modeloDisminuir(modelo, ejemplar);
   }
    return modeloEncontrado;
}
```

Esto es de una clase llamada Concesionaria, que recorre la lista de autos agregados.

```
 public boolean modeloDisminuir(String modelo, int ejemplar){
    //boolean si = false;
    /*if(){
        disminuirEjemplares(ejemplar);
        si = true;
    }*/
    return encontrarModelo2(modelo) && disminuirEjemplares(ejemplar) != 0;
}
```

Este es el metodo principal que alberga el disminuir y el encontrar el modelo deseado.

```
 public int disminuirEjemplares(int ejemplar){
    return cantidadDeEjemplares-=ejemplar;
}
```

Este codigo es para disminuir la cantidad de autos.

```
 private boolean encontrarModelo2(String modelo){
    return modelo().equalsIgnoreCase(modelo);
}
```

Aquí encuentro el modelo deseado por el usuario.

Lo que pasa es que cuando paso un argumento por Scanner (para que el usuario lo digite), el encontrar el modelo si lo hace perfectamente, pero para disminur no lo hace, si tienen alguna duda sobre el codigo, haganme saber comunidad :), muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu condicion del while, solo va a entrar una vez debido a que en la segunda iteracion `modeloEncontrado` ya tendra valor.

Modifica tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
while (it.hasNext() && modeloEncontrado == null) {
      Automotor a = it.next();
      if(a.encontrarModelo2(modelo)){
          modeloEncontrado = a;
          modeloEncontrado.modeloDisminuir(modelo, ejemplar);
      }
}
```

De esa manera estaras usando el metodo de tu auto para vaidar si es el mismo y solo disminuiras la cantidad si el modelo coincide.

El codigo completo quearia:

### Automotor

```
package com.github.javatlacati.respuestasstackoverflow.questions553382;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
class Automotor {

    int cantidadDeEjemplares;
    String modelo;

    public boolean modeloDisminuir(String modelo, int ejemplar) {
        return encontrarModelo2(modelo) && disminuirEjemplares(ejemplar) != 0;
    }

    public boolean encontrarModelo2(String modelo) {
        boolean modelosiguales = getModelo().equalsIgnoreCase(modelo);
        return modelosiguales;
    }

    private int disminuirEjemplares(int ejemplar) {
        return cantidadDeEjemplares -= ejemplar;
    }
    
}
```

### Concesionaria

```
package com.github.javatlacati.respuestasstackoverflow.questions553382;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class Concesionaria {

    private List<Automotor> listaDeAutomotores;

    public Automotor disminuirEjemplares(int ejemplar, String modelo) {
        Automotor modeloEncontrado = null;
        Iterator<Automotor> it = this.listaDeAutomotores.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext() && modeloEncontrado == null) {
            Automotor a = it.next();
            if(a.encontrarModelo2(modelo)){
                modeloEncontrado = a;
                modeloEncontrado.modeloDisminuir(modelo, ejemplar);
            }
        }
        return modeloEncontrado;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Concesionaria concesionaria = new Concesionaria(Arrays.asList(
                new Automotor(25, "Mastretta MXT"),
                new Automotor(7, "Quantum")
        ));
        
        System.out.println(concesionaria);
        concesionaria.disminuirEjemplares(2, "Quantum");
        System.out.println(concesionaria);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola manin, no funcionó como me dijiste loco :(, crees que afecte si Automotor es una clase Abstracta? Yo lo dudo la vdd... Sigue sin cambiar o bueno disminuir la cantidad establecida :(

Comment: una clase abstracta como si usaras Autovalue de Google? deberia. Con los datos que compartiste yo llego a esta solucion, tal vez debas hacer otra pregunta con otro [mcve] que se parezca mas a tu codigo real

Comment: Hasta lo intente con el disminuirEjemplares directamente y nada men.                   `if(a.encontrarModelo2(modelo)){
                modeloEncontrado = a;
                modeloEncontrado.disminuirEjemplares(ejemplar);
           }`

Comment: yo tambien, pero en mi caso si funciona :)